# How do I checkout a feature with git?

Tags: git, gitlab

I created a feature a few weeks ago with git and did some work on it and had to stop. Now I want to start working on it again but each time I use `git branch -a` to get the name of the available branches I can see it as

```
remotes/origin/feature/upgrade-free-premium
```

but when I run `git checkout upgrade-free-premium` I get the following error.

```
error: pathspec 'upgrade-free-premium' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Could someone help me solve this?

Comment: git checkout origin/upgrade-free-premium ?

Comment: Michael is right, you need to checkout the remote branch. But the right command is probably `git checkout -b upgrade-free-premium origin/feature/upgrade-free-premium`

Comment: Thanks @Luigi this did the trick   

git checkout -b upgrade-free-premium origin/feature/upgrade-free-premium

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
git checkout -b upgrade-free-premium origin/feature/upgrade-free-premium
```

In your case, the branch is a remote one. You need to specify from which branch you want to checkout: so the correct branch name is `origin/feature/upgrade-free-premium`. This, because other origins can have the same branch name, so you need to specify the full name.

The `-b` is necessary to create a local branch to track the remote branch.

Answer (score 4):

Your branch is named `feature/upgrade-free-premium` ('/' can be part of the branch name).

Run `git checkout feature/upgrade-free-premium` instead.

Comment: `checkout` will accept a branch name which exists only on origin and will create a local tracking branch of the same name for you. At least in git 1.8.0 the above would output `Branch feature/upgrade-free-premium set up to track remote branch feature/upgrade-free-premium from origin.`
`Switched to a new branch 'feature/upgrade-free-premium'`

Comment: Does the branch definitely exist on your remote repo? The only thing i can think of is that the remote repo has messed up for some reason.

Comment: Yes: branch -a shows the remote branch, if I don't specify remotes/origin/branch-name it doesn't check out. Also if you don't specify `-b` it won't create the local branch.

Comment: Looks like running this command did the trick and created a local branch from the remote server

    `git checkout -b upgrade-free-premium origin/feature/upgrade-free-premium`

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have your feature branch from develop
 1. git checkout develop
 2. git pull
 3. git checkout 
 4. git pull

Comment: This is actually a comment

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved it by doing `git pull` first and then `git checkout <feature>` :)